# Misspelled Data

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to correct below misspelled data in column market:

| market |
| --- |
| SocialMediaAdvertising |
| SocialInvesting |
| FinancialExchanges |
| CloudMagement |
| VentureCapital |

I don't know what syntax to write.
But output should be as below:

| market |
| --- |
| Social Media Advertising |
| Social Investing |
| Financial Exchanges |
| Cloud Magement |
| Venture Capital |

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the [regexp_replace()](https://%20https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) function to insert  each a space before each upper case letter. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/aIy_jJtA))

```
update markets  
   set market = ltrim(regexp_replace(market, '([A-Z])', ' \1', 'g'));
```

**Caution:** As presented this Updates every occurrence of an upper case letter inserting a space before it. The `ltrim` removes the space inserted at the beginning of the column. Any uppercase letter preceded by a space creates a double space. Make sure you validate result.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a series of SQL updates since there aren't many changes. For example

```sql
UPDATE your_table set market="Social Media Advertising" where market="SocialMediaAdvertising";
UPDATE your_table set market="Social Investing" where market="SocialInvesting";
UPDATE your_table set market="Financial Exchanges" where market="FinancialExchanges";
UPDATE your_table set market="Cloud Magement" where market="CloudMagement";
UPDATE your_table set market="Venture Capital" where market="VentureCapital";
```

**Cautions**:
Be sure to replace `your_table` with the actual name of the table you want to update, for each SQL statement.

You *might* have a typo with "Magement", but I'm not sure

Comment: Hi may I ask how about there were 600 different misspelled value,  is there a syntax that is shorter?

Comment: The management is really misspelled.

Comment: The double quotes are used to escape identifiers (column or table names) in SQL. String constants need to be written in single quotes. `"VentureCapital"` is a column reference `'VentureCapital'` is a string constant